# Trying to visit my website at /get_started redirects to / when I copy and paste, but not when I type it manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a rails app with a page at this url: http://yo4food.com/get_started

You'll notice that clicking the link redirects to http://yo4food.com/

However, if you add a /get_started to the end (type it manually) it does work.

any ideas what's going on?

`routes.rb` looks like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
      get 'get_started' => 'pages#get_started'
end
```

The root route isn't present because it just goes to `index.html` in the public folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://yo4food.com/get_started is redirecting to http://www.yo4food.com/

http://www.yo4food.com/get_started does not get redirected.